onEdit() e.source returning first sheet in spreadsheet, not edited sheet
For context, I have a google sheet that we use for inventory and pricing. I have made another spreadsheet that imports the ranges that we need from the original to show wholesale inventory to customers without any pricing. I am currently using ImportRange() to copy the content, but I would like to maintain the formatting of the previous sheet.
I am using this onEdit() script to update the formatting (I am using a trigger in the original):
function setFormatOnEdit(e) {
  if (!e)
    throw new Error("This function is automatically called, do not run this manually")
  const lock = LockService.getScriptLock()
  if (lock.tryLock(350000)) {
    try {
      const {
        master,
        sources
      } = variables_();
      const { range, source } = e;
      const { editRange } = sources.find(({ sheetName }) => sheetName == source.getSheetName());
      const srcRange = source.getRange(editRange);
      const editedSheetName = range.getSheet().getSheetName();
      if (editedSheetName != srcRange.getSheet().getSheetName())
        return;
      //Reformatting Code Here
    } catch ({stack}) {
      console.error(stack)
    } finally {
      lock.releaseLock();
      console.log("Done");
    }
  } else { console.error("Timeout") }
}

And variables_() is:
function variables_() {
  const masterSpreadsheetId = "###"

  const sourceSheetName1 = "Mixed Oak"
  ...
  const sourceSheetName13 = "Misc/Random Inventory"

  const sourceSheet1Range = "Mixed Oak!A1:I"
  ...
  const sourceSheet13Range = "Misc/Random Inventory!A1:I"

  return {
    master: { masterSpreadsheetId },
    sources: [
      { sheetName: sourceSheetName1, editRange: sourceSheet1Range },
      ...
      { sheetName: sourceSheetName13, editRange: sourceSheet13Range }
    ]
  };
}

Currently I am having the issue of e.source returning the first sheet in the source spreadsheet (which is a summary of pricing sheet; I do not want to copy this sheet over) after every edit, regardless of which sheet is edited.
This poses a problem because I am trying to use the sheet name of the edited original to reformat the copy sheet on each edit.
I could just use conditional formatting to reformat the copy, but there are less options possible and I would need to do a search through all rows for certain formatting parameters, which would take forever to update and is just clunky.
Let me know if there is a way to fix this issue, or if there is a better way to do what I am trying to do with copying over.

variables_() is undefined

variables_() is a function outside of this block. Plus that shouldn't matter on which sheet e.source returns.

the sheet being edited is e.range.getSheet();

So is source just returning the spreadsheet, and when asking for the sheet it just returns the first one?

Then  is should not be part of your [mcve] because we cannot reproduce it

Also I still have the problem where e.range.getSheet() returns the summary sheet as well even though I am editing the second sheet.

I have updated the post to include the varaibles_() function

The source property of the on-edit event trigger returns the active SpreasheetApp.Spreadsheet, not a SpreadsheetApp.Sheet.
On the other hand, the following part of the script in the question doesn't make sense to me:
const { editRange } = sources.find(({ sheetName }) => sheetName == source.getSheetName());
const srcRange = source.getRange(editRange);
const editedSheetName = range.getSheet().getSheetName();
if (editedSheetName != srcRange.getSheet().getSheetName())
        return;

If you are looking to get the edited range use e.range, e.source.getActiveSheet().getActiveRange() or SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getActiveRange(). The first option is preferred for brevity, and intuitively, it should be faster. Also, the object returned is extended with the properties rowStart, columnStart, rowEnd and columnEnd, which are handy in many use cases.
To get the name of the edited sheet you might use  e.range.getSheet().getName() or e.source.getActiveSheet().getName(), SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getName(). Any of the first two options are preferred.
Note: Regarding explaining spreadsheet concepts and how Google spreadsheet works, I think that the Google Sheets API documentation is more complete and clear than the documentation of the Google Apps Script Spreadsheet Service and even the Google Sheets section on https://support.google.com/docs. I mentioned this because the Google Sheets API documentation mentions how is determined the sheet or range to be returned on several cases.

Thanks for looking into this. The first line with the editRange variable is used to verify from a premade list, that the edited sheet is in fact one of the sheets that is being copied over. The rest is probably not helpful since it was verifying the source and range were from the same sheet...
I am still having an issue though where when I edit the 'Mixed Oak' sheet, the Logger.log(e.range.getSheet().getName()) from the trigger execution still returns 'Summary' instead.

@NathanGramm You might be looking at the wrong event. What are you doing to activate the onEdit trigger?

And maybe more importantly, you might be overthinking this... instead of using IMPORTRANGE and a script it's a lot better to use a script to copy values and format.

Ah yes, so I noticed that when I add a row, it outputs the 'Summary' sheet, but when changing the values of a cell it outputs the correct sheet name.
And yeah, perhaps I will look into just copying over the contents instead which should resolve that issue.

@NathanGramm, I think you are using on-change trigger instead of an on-edit trigger because an on-edit trigger is not activated when a row is inserted.
